# Multiple choice First principle Question

Tags: calculus, derivatives

[image: This is the question at hand. I have tried manipulating the 3 to bring it forward.]

Answers say C. I originally factored the 3 out so essentially it is f(3(a/3 + h)) meaning function is actually f'(3x). We sub in x as alpha /3.

Comment: A good sanity check for questions like this is to try it for an explicit function, $f(x)=x$ for example.  Of course, a few examples isn't a proof but a single example can disprove some (most?) of the options.

Answer (score 1):

It's    $$\color{blue}3\lim\limits_{h\to0}\dfrac{f(a+3h)-f(a)}{\color{blue}3h}.$$